# I'm trying to learn, or revise from Artin algebra, 2nd edition

Tags: reference-request

I'm trying to learn, or revise, Artin algebra, 2nd edition. I'm working alone; that is, I'm self-learning. It is quite fun. But the problem is how do I check if I've managed to arrive at a correct solution to an exercise problem? Can I get hold of a solution manual? Or, can I find someone over the Internet with whom I can discuss my solutions? Of course, putting up every other problem at Mathematics Stack Exchange, it seems to me, is not so practical!

What would be the best possible for me?

Comment: Google Artin Second edition solutions. There are a few sites with solutions to the whole book.

Comment: you can post your solutions (to some problems where you doubt that is correctly solved) here, in math.stackexchange, with the tag `proof verification`. I do it time to time if Im not totally sure of my solution to some exercise of some textbook